# ExpressJS Modules with Controller/Manager

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to create an API using express, but having difficulties with the initial setup, I'd like to have separate classes for the controllers & managers, but keep getting the following error when trying to register my routes:

```
Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
```

Here is my setup so far:

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var UserController = require('./lib/controllers/user/user.controller');

userController = new UserController();

app.use('/user', userController);

app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening on port 3000...');

module.exports = app;
```

**user.controller.js**

```
const {register, login} = require('../routes').user;
var userManager = require('../../managers/user/user.manager');
const express = require('express');
const expressApp = express.Router();

class UserController {

constructor(
    ) {
        userManager = new userManager();    
        this.expressApp.post(register, this.register.bind(this));
    }

    register(request, response) {
        return userManager
            .register(request)
            .then(result => response.status(statusCodes.OK).json(result))
            .catch(e);
    }
}

module.exports = UserController;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `UserController`'s `constructor`.

You're trying to use `this.expressApp` while `this.expressApp` is not defined.

Comment: Ah of course.. thanks, that's fixed the initial problem. 

Can you advise how I can properly set up my routes from app.js to map to those defined within my user controller? I get the following error: 

Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object.
I can see why but unsure how I can fix this problem?

Comment: This might probably help you : https://hackernoon.com/object-oriented-routing-in-nodejs-and-express-71cb1baed9f0

Comment: Thanks for your help! Much appreciated :)